# How to get post id using ShareDialog?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

How to get the post id of the post created by native `ShareDialog` using `FacebookBroadcastReceiver.onSuccessfulAppCall`?

NOTE : `FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>.onSuccess` invoked with `result.getPostId()` as null

Comment: I think the user must grant the app publish_actions for you to get it. Why do you need it?

Comment: @WizKid Does it really matter?, this should be trivial as you create posts you might want to access/edit/remove them later...

Comment: Yes it matters because most people that want it want to use it for share gating which is not allowed.

Comment: @WizKid what are you basing your statement "sharing gating is not allowed" on? the API does have a partially implemented "sharing gating" as you define it already, if you post a simple post its id will be given to you onSuccess by result.getPostId() seem unlikely that this exists while forbiden

Comment: I'm basing that on the Facebook Platform Policy 4.5 as you can read at https://developers.facebook.com/policy . As you said it can be used for other things then share gating. But to get it you need to be approved for publish_actions and you will not get approved if you use it for share gating

Comment: I have noticed that Facebook behaves differently if you don't have Facebook application on your device. In that case, you share through your browser and it always gets into `onSuccess`, but result.getPostId() is not null if post is actually shared.